# cmake fails with "Could NOT find HDF5"

Tags: 12.04, cmake

My project compiles flawlessly in Mac OS X and now that I try building in Ubuntu 12.x latest as of today, I get the error `-- Could NOT find HDF5 (missing:  HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS)`. If I take the HDF5-dev package using apt-get cmake will find HDF5 but my code will not compile due to the HDF5-dev package being older.

I tried downloading the latest HDF5 and building from source:

```
cd $HDF5_ROOT
./configure /usr/local/hdf5
sudo make install
```

and this successfully installs HDF5 under directory `/usr/local/hdf5` but cmake won't find it. I also tried setting the environment variables `$HDF5_ROOT` and `$HDF5_ROOT_DIR_HINT` but still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try to update your `PATH`:

```bsh
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/hdf5"
```

Additionally, you can change `PATH` in your `~/.profile`:

```bsh
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="/usr/local/hdf5:$HOME/bin:$PATH" #this line
fi
```

This is just a guess; hope to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This Solved my same issue :

- I `unzip` and `configure` hdf5 in `/src/hdf5-1.8.14` and did a `make install`.
- It created a directory `/src/hdf5-1.8.14/hdf5` with `lib`, `include`, `bin` in it and VTK compile failed on:

  ```
  Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS)
  ```

Solved with:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/src/hdf5-1.8.14/hdf5
```